# Can an Android App fill a web form without showing the web form to the user?

Tags: javascript, android, python

This is a conceptual idea for learning purpose. I don't know whether it is possible or not. 
I have an Android activity with some text fields and a button. The same form is in the web. What I need is;
when user fill and press the button on the android interface, it should fill the web form and press the button on web form (may be using JAVA script or something, I don't know). 
I don't need the codes, but just an exact idea how to do this. :)

Please check the image for what I have in my mind. But I cannot determine how and where to apply a JAVA script (if needed)

Can anyone give me an idea please. 
[image]

Comment: Its possible you need to work around reactive approach i.e. event driven along nodeserver or React PHP or anyother on client end try ReactJS or any other reactive library. try it :)

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question!

I can think on two alternatives:

1. You could post the android form to the service that the web form uses in its target attribute.
2. If you need to fill the web form and post it:

   - 2.1 When you press the OK button in the android form, you can open the web form in a webView (which could be hidden somehow), setting in the url the parameters containing the android form fields' values.
   - 2.2 In the web form, using javascript, check if there are parameters in the URL. If parameters are present, then fill the form and submit it (also using javascript).

Answer (score 0):

That's the round about way of doing it.  Instead, you should just have your android form make a direct HTTP request just like the submit of the form would.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple method.Whether you are doing in php,asp or jsp write the code for the same for the page to insert the data and apply the **GET method**. Then build the page(where you need) for selecting the data and encode into **json** form. Then in your android try applying the following code:(by changing the url and the form fields name):

```
    package ex.even78;

   import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
   import java.io.InputStream;
     import java.io.InputStreamReader;
   import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
   import java.util.ArrayList;

 import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
 import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.CursorJoiner.Result;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class firstact extends Activity implements  Z{
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
EditText edt;
TextView tv;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    edt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
    tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

}
public void method(View v) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, JSONException
{
    HttpClient hc=new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost hp=new HttpPost("http://www.akshaychatterjee.in/aks.php");
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> al=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    al.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phone", "3828929"));
    al.add(new BasicNameValuePair("session", "dsfsd"));
    hp.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(al));
    HttpResponse hr=hc.execute(hp);
    InputStream in=hr.getEntity().getContent();
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in,"iso-8859-1"),8);
    StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
    String ss;
    while((ss=br.readLine())!=null)
    {
        sb.append(ss+"\n");
    }

}
public void getdata(View v) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, JSONException 
{


    HttpClient hc=new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost hp=new HttpPost("http://www.akshaychatterjee.in/aks1.php");
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> al=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    al.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phone","34232"));
    hp.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(al));
    HttpResponse hr=hc.execute(hp);
    InputStream in=hr.getEntity().getContent();
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in,"iso-8859-1"),8);
    StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
    String ss;
    while((ss=br.readLine())!=null)
    {
        sb.append(ss+"\n");
    }

    JSONObject jo=new JSONObject(sb.toString());
    String pass=jo.getString("session");
    Toast.makeText(this, pass, 1).show();

    in.close();
    /*class db extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
    {

        StringBuilder sb;

    String pass;
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            HttpClient hc=new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost hp=new HttpPost("http://www.akshaychatterjee.in/aks1.php");
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> al=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            al.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phone","34232"));
            try {
                hp.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(al));
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            HttpResponse hr = null;
            try {
                hr = hc.execute(hp);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            InputStream in = null;
            try {
                in = hr.getEntity().getContent();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            BufferedReader br = null;
            try {
                br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
             sb=new StringBuilder();
            String ss;
            try {
                while((ss=br.readLine())!=null)
                {
                    sb.append(ss+"\n");
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return pass;
        }
           protected void onPostExecute(String...  arg0)  {

               tv.setText(pass);
        }


    }*/
    //db d=new db();
    //d.execute();
}
```

}
i.e. you have to use the HTtpclient to knock your server and HTTPOst to apply the method to  the form to get the data  and collect them by connecting through a JSONobject .(BasicNamevaluepair are used to add the data or insert it or select by its field's name in the form  in arraylist form.)

For auto filling you take the resonse data from mobile in that website in another page  by httppost and then by applying ajax in the form page you take the data entered in the other page in the fields ,without refreshing it should come.

Comment: You are not filling in a form at all.